# Как поправить кнопку назад в браузере?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть сайт с музыкой и чтобы музыка не прерывалась была сделана реализация переходов по ссылкам через аякс, но с этим возникла пролбема. Точнее, кнопка назад в браузере не работает и не возвращает пользователя на предыдущую страницу.

```
$('body').on('click','.wajax',function(){
    var $urlNext = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($urlNext !== undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $urlNext,
            beforeSend: function() {
                ShowLoading('');
            },           
            success: function(data) {
                $('.content').html($('.content', data).html());
                window.history.pushState("", "", $urlNext);
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 'slow');
                var title = (/\<title>(.*[\s\S]*?)\<\/title>/g).exec(data)[1];
                if(title.length != 0){ $('head title').text(title); };
                HideLoading('');
               docready();
            },
              error: function() {               
                HideLoading('');
                alert('что-то пошло не так');
              }
        });
    };
    return false;
});
```

я так понимаю проболема в `window.history.pushState("", "", $urlNext);`

[полный код js](https://hit.edit-web.site/templates/music-tmp/js/libs.js)

[ссылка на сайт с проблемой](https://hit.edit-web.site/)

Comment: При переходе назад браузер запускает событие popstate, и вы должны обработать его и самостоятельно вернуть содержимое предыдущей страницы